# how can I do an image overlay without fading text?

Tags: css, overlay

I'm trying to have an image with an overlay and some text over it. The overlay I have works fine, but the text is also fading which I don't want. I'd like the text to stay the same. here is some of my code
html:

```
<div class="hero">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="header">
          <h1 class="overlay-text"</h1>
          <p class="text-center overlay-text">SOME CONTENT HERE</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

css:

```
.hero {
  background-image: url('http://localhost:3000/3b1425242c422b429f78f272b0a4c0f7.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-height: 101vh;
  color: white;
}
.hero:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.overlay-text {
  z-index: 200;
}
.overlay-text:after {
  z-index: 200;
}
```

.overlay text was just something I tried, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a little example: https://jsfiddle.net/zydkz1ed/1/
You just need to make `.overlay-text` absolute or relative in order for `z-index` to works:

```
.overlay-text {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

Also the h1 tag wasn't quite right, it should be: `<h1 class="overlay-text"></h1>`. There was a missing `>` sign.